# How to filter a complex response in karate dsl using jsonPath?

Tags: json, jmeter, karate, json-path-expression

I am getting below response from a REST API, but I am finding it difficult to extract label value from the received response and assign it to a variable to use it later in script.
Here is the RESPONSE::

```
{
  "result": "SUCCESS",
  "rawAttr": "[{\"attributes\":[{\"name\":\"resourceid\",\"value\":\"7A7Q123456\"},{\"name\":\"physicalid\",\"value\":\"7A7Q123456\"},{\"name\":\"dsw:label\",\"value\":\"MY Product00004285\"},{\"name\":\"dsw:created\",\"value\":\"2019-11-06T08:39:39Z\"}]}]",
  "physicalid": "7A7Q123456",
  "contextPath": "/path",
  "id": "7A7Q123456",
  "message": null
}
```

I am able to get `response.id` and `response.result` which is helpful for validation but I am not able to get the `dsw:label` `value` which is `MY Product00004285`

When I do `def Arr = response.rawAttr` I get the below value whether it is Array or String I am confused. Seems like it is a string.

```
[{"attributes":[{"name":"resourceid","value":"7A7Q123456"},{"name":"physicalid","value":"7A7Q123456"},{"name":"dsw:label","value":"MY Product00004298"},{"name":"dsw:created","value":"2019-11-06T08:39:39Z"}]}]
```

It is very easy to extract the label in JMeter JSON Extractor using below JSON Path expression 
`$.attributes.value[2]`

Comment: *"Seems like it is a string."* Correct. `rawAttr` is JSON. You need to parse it.

Comment: @Tomalak will try that way also. But I think karate has some good features to extract data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer Karate's type conversion capabilities: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

So you can do this:

```
* json attr = response.rawAttr
```

And then you are all set.

Comment: Peter, where can I connect with you one to one to share a scenario which I am finding bit difficult to post in SO. Everything is perfect in .feature file but I am not getting the expected result.

Comment: follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: it is not an issue with karate, I want to have a screen sharing or zoom session with you. Scenario works fine with JMeter but fails in karate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to an example and documentation on converting string to json.
Got it how to do.

```
And def strVar = response.rawAttr
And json jsonVar = strVar
And def attrb = karate.jsonPath(jsonVar, '$..attributes.[2].value')[0]
And print '\n\n Attrb\n', attrb
```

Links I referred:
[Json Path evaluator](http://jsonpath.com/)
[Karate doc reference for type conversion](https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion)
[Karate example for type-conversion](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/type-conv.feature)